# Microsoft Office 2016 Highlight/Search Multiple Words all Caps

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, search

Is it possible to search for specific words in a word document?

To describe the documents I am using. They can be over 50 pages long. The part I am interested in is the addresses.

I would like the word to highlight the states which are abbreviated like MN WI etc. It standard addresses so the states are precedided by a comma like , MN or , WI
ALL 50 states are a possibility so I am looking for something that could highlight all of these.

I was able to do this on LibreOffice, but this is not available where I work. I was having trouble finding the same feature in microsoft office.

Comment: How exactly you could do it in LibreOffice? Are all upper case two-letter words starts abbreviations in your document, or are there some which you need to exclude?

Comment: Advanced search and find
regular Expression
capital match you just do find all the search is something like
(AZIMN....all 50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a wildcard find and replace - but before you start, highlight some text first so that there is a highlight color (and not no color) which the replace will then use.

Since you know it is always a comma followed by 2 capital letters, the following find should work:

[image]

Comment: That is a clever way to get to my goal. this seems like it will work. Though I am not sure if it will end up deleting the words instead of highlighting them.  I will have to test it in a few hours.

Thank you getting closer to what I want.